# I want to export a single database and import it in another instance

Tags: google-cloud-sql

We've multiple databases under 1 mysql instance on gcp. I want to export a single database (that should include SP, Triggers, views, tables, data) from gcp mysql and import it in another instance. My database would have 100gb of data e.g, i tried gcloud export but that does not import SP. mysqldump would be the option for the same but not sure how to use it to export it in a bucket and import it as new database. Can you please help me here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ["Can Someone Help Me" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Answer (score 0):

Cloud SQL instances must have Binary logging enabled in order to replicate and create Backups. When Binary logging is enabled, Trigger creation requires SUPER privileges on the MySQL server [1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html). Upon investigating this issue I found that this is also the case for Stored Procedures.

In Cloud SQL, you can't have users with SUPER privileges [2](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/users#superuser_restrictions).

One way to workaround this is to set the log_bin_trust_function_creators flag [3](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_bin_trust_function_creators) in the Cloud SQL instance [4](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#mysql-l). In order to use this flag safely you should be sure that the stored procedures/triggers will have the same result in the master as well as in the replicas. If you are confident about that, you should not have any issue.

If you wanted to export the triggers alongside the stored procedures when using the mysqldump command, you should add the --triggers flag [5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_triggers).

To sum up:
To export stored procedures from a Cloud SQL instance, include the --routines flag. To export triggers from a Cloud SQL instance, make sure that --skip-triggers is not specified. If binary logging is enabled and you want to export triggers and stored procedures, you must also set the log_bin_trust_function_creators flag in your MySQL database